# Is AWS free tier per-project?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Can you create two AWS projects and have a separate always free limit in between the two of them? I can not find any articles documenting this on the internet and am wondering if anyone with experience knows about this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s about specific service and SO is not their customer or sales service

Comment: AWS does not have a concept of "Project'.

Comment: I only work with AWS and I have no idea what project means here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are confused between GCP and Amazon accounts and project concepts. In AWS there is no concept of a project but you can create as many accounts as possible. For exploration purposes, you may create two projects linked to two different email Ids. For any real use case, you may not want to follow this approach.

The concept of free tier is applied per account. But if your idea is to run some commercial software on AWS by simply using the free tier by creating different accounts, then I believe you will end up spending more man hours managing this mess than the benefit you will get.

Answer (score 1):

No, free tier is intended for per account, not per project